# vue-router : Navigation not routing to correct path

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am using `vuex` and `vue-router`. I have a client's zone, when you try to loggin, you should go to the profil. But it's not happend.

```
routes: [
{
  path: "/area-do-cliente",
  name: "customerZone",
  redirect: "/area-do-cliente/profile",
  component: () =>
    import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "ClientZone" */ "@/scenes/ClientZone/views/ClientZone.vue"
    ),
  children: [
    {
      path: "login",
      name: "login",
      component: () => import("@/scenes/ClientZone/components/LogIn.vue"),
      props: true,
      meta: { clientZoneLogin: true }
    },
    {
      path: "profile",
      name: "profile",
      component: () => import("@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Profile.vue"),
      meta: { clientZoneAuthRequired: true, clientZoneLogin: true },
      props: true
        },
      ]
    }
  ]


  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(_to => _to.meta.clientZoneLogin))
    if (store.getters.personData.status == "1") {
     console.log("01");
     router({ name: "profile" });
   } else {
     console.log("2");
     next();
     }
   } else {
     console.log("3");
    next();
  }
  }
 });
```

So I still have in `console` => 2. It is mean that I pass the first condition, but I shouldnt. I have status 1, and the response of this data is when you click the login button (there is a event).

```
 methods: {
 doLogin: function() {
    this.error = "";
    let loginData = {
    login: this.login,
    password: this.password
  };
   this.isLoading = true;
   this.errorMessage = "";
   co.postLogin(loginData)
    .then(data => {
      this.$store.commit("personData", data.data); // here I push data to store
   )}
   }
  }
```

Any ideas where is mistake?

Comment: If the console is outputting `2` then this has nothing to do with the router _not routing to correct path_ and has everything to do with `store.getters.personData.status` not being equal to `1`.

Comment: But I `console.log` this `store.getters.personData.status` and it really is 1.  I can not understand why it doesn't fall into the first condition?

Comment: Are you sure it's `1` the number and not `"1"` as a string?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but nothing has changed :( Stil `2` in console.

Comment: If it's still logging `2`, you need to find out what the value of `store.getters.personData.status` is at the point of execution as it's not `1`. Add a `console.log('status', store.getters.personData.status)` before the `if`

Comment: Yeah it's really not `1` in the moment of execution :/ So the problem is probably in logic, not syntax. Thaks for this. I have to analyze again this problem.